# All canal types of mandible premolar teeth

Tags: dentistry, root-canal

Is there any case with a mandible premolar tooth with distal and mesial canals? I have a problem with finding the canals of the mentioned tooth. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is it the first premolar or the second premolar? Also, what's the reason for your question?

Comment: @Oj16 Dear friend, I am a dentist and it is one of my complicated cases that needs to some guide to be treated well. By the way, it is the second premolar. I know it is kind of rediculus, but is there any possibility to have a two (mesial and distal) canal tooth?!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible for the mandibular second premolar to have two roots canals or even at times [three](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4099958/%23:%7E:text%3DMost%2520mandibular%2520second%2520molars%2520have,distal%2520and%2520mesial%2520roots%252C%2520respectively.%26text%3DAfter%2520access%2520cavity%2520preparation%252C%2520two,two%2520distal%2520orifices%2520were%2520found.&ved=2ahUKEwjhj_6H_-zqAhULeisKHdyrDAcQFjABegQIDBAH&usg=AOvVaw2dzw68uJqN4ODFscODCu4l) canals!
Here is a [case](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.oraljournal.com/pdf/2016/vol2issue4/PartB/2-4-2.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjhj_6H_-zqAhULeisKHdyrDAcQFjANegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw3jEJOP3LaPDbZ9BG1O7Y1thttps://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.oraljournal.com/pdf/2016/vol2issue4/PartB/2-4-2.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjhj_6H_-zqAhULeisKHdyrDAcQFjANegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw3jEJOP3LaPDbZ9BG1O7Y1t) of the same.
According to Grossman, in 2.5% cases a single canal may bifurcate existing in two foramina.
Hence it is recommended to take a Cone Beam Computer Tomography and use an apex locator to eliminate confusions.

Comment: @Perfect Fluid you may accept the answer if you are satisfied with it for the future reference